# How to fetch Sports Complexes and Fields in Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I would like to fetch Sports Complexes/ Fields and even apartments, how can I get that?
Currently I get very few results in the Auto-Complete.

**Package Name:** `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` .
 **API:** `GooglePlacesAutocomplete`

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        query={{
          // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
          key: ,
          language: "en", // language of the results
          types: "address" // default: 'geocode'
        }}

        nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
        GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={
          {
            // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
          }
        }
        GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
          // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
          rankby: "distance"
        }}
        filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={[
          "locality",
          "administrative_area_level_3"
        ]} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
        // predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}
        debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
      />
```

`filterReverseGeocodingByTypes` is something I should be taking care of but I'm not sure how to get all the Sport Complexes, Fields and Apartments.

If I can get all the result, like we get in Google Maps, it would be fine as well.

example `City, Locality, Schools and everything.`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't accessible with the current API. The list of currently support types can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types).

However, you could add

```
GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
    // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
    rankby: 'distance',
    type: 'stadium' 
  }}
```

Specifying the type as `stadium` is the closest you'll get to fetching Sports Complexes and Fields however the results will not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the type "sports_complex" are not yet currently supported. However, if you really need this feature to be added in our API, you can file a Feature Request in our [**Google Public Issue Tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com).

**Issue Tracker** is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

Thank you very much!